# Progress bar loading Image from URL in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I develop an application that loads large images from URL (more than 3 MB).

When I load these images, fabric takes a few seconds to insert this.

There are some method to implement a progress bar while fabric loads this image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: questions like these get downvotes these days